# Behavior of "Open Selection" CTRL+D

Tags: matlab

How can I tell MATLAB to open a variable (double click, CTRL+D) in the same window as the variable I am already inspecting? Currently, my MATLAB always opens a new inspection window when openening a variable, which gets confusing quickly.

I can send all variables to the same window (with multiple tabs) using "Dock All in Variables", which gives me the desired behavior until I undock one variable. Also, I lose my (maybe intended) separation of variable-inspection-windows.

*So I want to be able to have multiple "Variables" windows, where an opened variable of a window is displayed using a tab in this specific window.*